# Only keep rows with specific condition in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm processing my logs using PySpark. I have two dataframes, one: `logs` DF is storing search `queries` and the other one: `clicks` DF is storing clicked document `IDs`.

Here is their following structure:

```
+-------------------+-------+----------------------+
|timestamp          |user   |query                 |
+-------------------+-------+----------------------+
|2021-12-01 06:14:38|m96cles|minoration            |
|2021-12-01 06:32:54|m96ngro|associés              |
|2021-12-01 06:40:40|m96mbeg|cessation             |
|2021-12-01 07:02:42|m96ngro|membres de société    |
|2021-12-01 07:02:58|m96ngro|cumul                 |
|2021-12-01 07:07:30|m96rara|cessation             |
|2021-12-01 07:09:37|m64nesc|INVF                  |
|2021-12-01 07:16:14|m83ccat|report didentifiation |
+-------------------+-------+----------------------+
+-------------------+-------+------+
|timestamp          |user   |doc_id|
+-------------------+-------+------+
|2021-12-01 06:14:42|m96cles|783   |
|2021-12-01 06:33:38|m96ngro|6057  |
|2021-12-01 06:40:52|m96mbeg|1407  |
|2021-12-01 06:49:12|m96mbeg|1414  |
|2021-12-01 06:53:19|m51cstr|15131 |
|2021-12-01 06:53:35|m51cstr|14992 |
|2021-12-01 06:53:55|m51cstr|15093 |
|2021-12-01 06:54:20|m51cstr|15110 |
+-------------------+-------+------+
```

I merged both dataframes by doing `df = logs.unionByName(clicks, allowMissingColumns=True)`, and sorted it by `timestamp`.

```
+-------------------+--------+--------------------+------+
|          timestamp|    user|               query|doc_id|
+-------------------+--------+--------------------+------+
|2022-05-31 20:23:40|ozenfada|                null|  7931|
|2022-05-31 21:06:44| m97emou|    apnée du sommeil|  null|
|2022-05-31 21:28:24| m64lbeh|                null|   192|
|2022-05-31 21:29:04| m97emou|                null|  3492|
+-------------------+--------+--------------------+------+
```

The idea is to only keep rows with search `queries` that lead to clicks. I don't want to keep logs that lead to no clicks on documents. In order to achieve this, I'm trying to look at next rows with the same `user` and see if they clicked at least on one document within 5 minutes. In the end, I only want to keep rows with search `query` values.

Here's what I've done so far, I tried to create a boolean column:

```
df = df.withColumn('valid', 
                    df.user == F.lead('user').over(
                        W.partitionBy(clicks.user, F.window('timestamp', '5 minutes')).orderBy('timestamp')
                    )
)
```

Here's the desired output. Notice how only rows with search queries that lead to clicks (a search query row (`query != null`) that is followed by "`clicks`" row(s) (`doc_id != null`) with the same username) have the `true` flag. Also, the row with `query` "rech" lead to a query correction "recherche" and therefore shouldn't be flagged as `true`.

```
+-------------------+--------+----------------------------------------+------+-----+
|timestamp          |user    |query                                   |doc_id|valid|
+-------------------+--------+----------------------------------------+------+-----+
|2022-05-31 18:56:47|m97bcar |exemple                                 |null |false|
|2022-05-31 19:22:40|ozenfada|fort                                    |null  |true |
|2022-05-31 19:23:40|ozenfada|null                                    |7931  |false|
|2022-05-31 19:24:09|ozenfada|null                                    |1034  |false|
|2022-05-31 21:06:44|m97emou |apnée du sommeil                        |null  |true |
|2022-05-31 21:07:24|m64lbeh |rech                                    |192   |false|
|2022-05-31 21:07:40|m64lbeh |recherche                               |null  |true |
|2022-05-31 21:08:21|m64lbeh |null                                    |3002  |false|
|2022-05-31 21:11:04|m97emou |null                                    |3492  |false|
+-------------------+--------+----------------------------------------+------+-----+
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

Comment: That's not very clear. Can you provide a dataframe with your expected result for the exemple you gave?

Comment: @LuizViola I edited my post and added the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will get you all the queries that resulted in a click within 5 minutes. Join on `user` will work with the extra condition that the `timestamp` difference between query and click is `<=5` minutes. The result printed below is for the sample data provided.

```py
# rename columns to avoid ambiguity
logs = logs.withColumnRenamed('timestamp', 'query_timestamp')
clicks = clicks.withColumnRenamed('timestamp', 'click_timestamp')
clicks = clicks.withColumnRenamed('user', 'click_user')

# join on same username, and if the click is within 5 minutes of the query
time_diff_in_seconds = F.unix_timestamp(clicks['click_timestamp']) - F.unix_timestamp(logs['query_timestamp'])
join_cond = (logs['user']==clicks['click_user']) & \
            (time_diff_in_seconds >= 0) & \
            (time_diff_in_seconds <= 5*60)
df2 = logs.join(clicks, join_cond, how='left')
# drop all queries that didn't lead to a click
df2 = df2.filter(df2['doc_id'].isNotNull())
# select only the necessary columns
df2 = df2.select('query_timestamp', 'user', 'query').distinct()

df2.show()

+-------------------+-------+----------+
|    query_timestamp|   user|     query|
+-------------------+-------+----------+
|2021-12-01 06:14:38|m96cles|minoration|
|2021-12-01 06:40:40|m96mbeg| cessation|
|2021-12-01 06:32:54|m96ngro|  associés|
+-------------------+-------+----------+
```

---

**Update - To handle misspelled queries**

Introduce a column that shows the time difference in seconds between a query and a click. After the join both rows will be retained but the time difference will be larger for the misspelled query. So do an `orderBy()` on time difference and drop the second row. This can be done with a `dropDuplicates('click_timestamp', 'user', 'doc_id')`.

Let's say there was a search for `minor` in the 2nd row:

```py
+-------------------+-------+--------------------+
|          timestamp|   user|               query|
+-------------------+-------+--------------------+
|2021-12-01 06:14:38|m96cles|          minoration|
|2021-12-01 06:14:39|m96cles|               minor|
... and rest of the rows
```

```py
logs = logs.withColumnRenamed('timestamp', 'query_timestamp')
clicks = clicks.withColumnRenamed('timestamp', 'click_timestamp')
clicks = clicks.withColumnRenamed('user', 'click_user')

time_diff_in_seconds = F.unix_timestamp(clicks['click_timestamp']) - F.unix_timestamp(logs['query_timestamp'])
join_cond = (logs['user']==clicks['click_user']) & \
            (time_diff_in_seconds >= 0) & \
            (time_diff_in_seconds <= 5*60)
df2 = logs.join(clicks, join_cond, how='left')

df2 = df2.withColumn('time_diff_in_seconds', time_diff_in_seconds)
# ensures if a query leads to multiple clicks then duplicates caused due to left join are dropped
df2 = df2.orderBy('time_diff_in_seconds').dropDuplicates(['query_timestamp', 'user', 'query'])
# keep only the latest query that lead to a click
df2 = df2.orderBy('time_diff_in_seconds').dropDuplicates(['click_timestamp', 'user', 'doc_id'])
df2 = df2.filter(df2['doc_id'].isNotNull())
df2 = df2.select('query_timestamp', 'user', 'query')

df2.show()

+-------------------+-------+---------+
|    query_timestamp|   user|    query|
+-------------------+-------+---------+
|2021-12-01 06:14:39|m96cles|    minor|
|2021-12-01 06:32:54|m96ngro| associés|
|2021-12-01 06:40:40|m96mbeg|cessation|
+-------------------+-------+---------+
```

You may need to test for more complex scenarios, and perhaps modify the code a bit. I think this logic would work, based on the sample data.

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there a way I can get rid of misspelled search queries? For example: if a user searches "exampl" without clicking on any documents, then proceeds to search "example" right after and starts clicking on documents? That would mean to only keep the latter query.

Comment: @cdaveau, I have updated the answer. Also, there is another condition I missed, timestamp difference should be `>=0` which I have added.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The join operation seems to be very slow and I don't understand one thing: why are we doing a `left join` and then deleting duplicates instead of doing an `inner join`? Isn't there another solution that would run faster? I have about 6 million rows in the `clicks` DF.